# Follow redirects from server until TLD matches pattern

Tags: proxy, mod-proxy, squid

I need to setup a proxy server to do the following:

1. User Requests a page from a server which I am hosting
2. Server returns me a link
3. The link in turn can re-direct to multiple links using standard 301s
4. Server follows redirects until url matches a specific pattern

What I want to achieve is this:
When the user hits my server, I want to follow the re-directs passing along the X-Forwarded-For header to indicate to the redirecting servers that the request originated from host X. At the end of the re-directions at step 4, when the re-direct URL matches a specific pattern, I want to forward the page as is to the end user.

Is this possible? If yes, how should I go about configuring such a setup?